# Validate a single field against a result from a service in Spring MVC

Tags: java, forms, validation, jsp, spring-mvc

I can't figure out how to do a simple, 1-field validation where I check the value against a service (or really any other logic check).

Most of the form validation I see uses a class to hold form data using javax.validation and marking up with attributes like @NotNull, @Min(10), etc. And then checking a BindingResult.hasErrors(). Like here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

I'm trying to do this for a single field and I want to validate against what a service will return to me rather than one of those validation attributes.

What do I put in my POST handler in the controller to get this going?

This is what I have in my controller to manage the result from the form

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myController", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkFieldVal(@RequestParam String valFromForm){
    if(!myService.isThisValueGood(valFromForm)) {
        //Show the user their value is bad
    }
    //return to some other page
}
```

And this is in my JSP (something simple like this):

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
    <label for="valueToCheck">What's your value:</label>
    <input type="text" id="valueToCheck" name="valueToCheck"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
 <form id="form" method="POST">
```

With adding the `action` like this:

```
 <form action="myController" id="form" method="POST">
```

And replace this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/myController", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String checkFieldVal(@RequestParam String valFromForm){
```

With adding the right name:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/myController", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String checkFieldVal(@RequestParam("valueToCheck") String valueToCheck){
```

Answer (score 1):

The param name must match in both controller and html.

```
@RequestParam String valFromForm

<input ... name="valueToCheck">
```

**Option 1**: Leaving jsp as it is, you change controller code as,

```
@RequestParam String valueToCheck
```

Or you may add qualifier to parameter name as,

```
@RequestParam("valueToCheck") String valFromForm
```

**Option 2**: Leaving controller as it is, you change jsp as,

```
<input ... name="valFromForm">
```